# How do i set django setting to a file which is outside the django tree?

Tags: python, django

I have this python file tasks.py

```
import os
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'DjangoWebProject.settings')
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from logreg.models import ActivationCode
    import datetime

    def remove_users():
        print 'hello worldddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd'
        inactive_users = []
        activation_codes = ActivationCode.objects.all()
        for activation_code in activation_codes:
            if datetime.datetime.date(activation_code.key_expires) < datetime.datetime.date(datetime.datetime.now()):
                inactive_users.append(activation_code.user_id)

        for inactive_user in inactive_users:
            User.objects.filter(id=inactive_user).delete()
```

But this is in the root folder and when i try to execute it, it gives me the following error

> File
>   "C:\Users\deybala1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dj
>   ango\apps\registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
>       raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're creating any script that is using your django project, it is absolutely necessary to set path to settings of your project **before** any import from django or your project. And you're importing user model from django in 1st line and model from your project in second.

Also, you will need to call `django.setup()` first.

To fix that, move `import os` and setting path to django settings to the very beginning of your script, and put django.setup() just after that (with proper import), like this:

```
# first, set path to project settings
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'DjangoWebProject.settings')
import django
django.setup()

# now you can import anything else
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from logreg.models import ActivationCode
import datetime

def remove_users():
    print 'hello worldddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd'
    inactive_users = []
    activation_codes = ActivationCode.objects.all()
    for activation_code in activation_codes:
        if datetime.datetime.date(activation_code.key_expires) < datetime.datetime.date(datetime.datetime.now()):
            inactive_users.append(activation_code.user_id)

    for inactive_user in inactive_users:
        User.objects.filter(id=inactive_user).delete()
```

Comment: Thanks for the hookup but now I get this error     File "C:\Users\deybala1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dj
ango\apps\registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Comment: Ah, because you're also missing `django.setup()` call. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you're trying to add a settings module inside a script that already requires it.

Wouldn't it be easier if you add a specific django command? Thanks to it you'd be able to start your task with `python manage.py --settings=<path_to_your_settings>`.

Another tip:

Move every django import statement below

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'DjangoWebProject.settings')
```